# Json output shows empty array

Tags: php, json

I am using php to retrieve data from localhost wampserver. The script is below:

```
$sql = "select * from topic";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

$topicarray[] = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $topicarray['topic'][] = $row;
}

print(json_encode($topicarray));

?>
```

the json output contains all the data but also includes one extra element in starting.I am not able to figure out what is that and how to remove that. the o/p is shown below:

```
{"0":[],"topic":[{"Topic_id":"1","Subject":"Computer Science","Details":"Consist of various subjects","Parent_id":null},{"Topic_id":"2","Subject":"Electronics","Details":"Subjects related to electronics","Parent_id":null},{"Topic_id":"3","Subject":"databases","Details":"Will talk about sql","Parent_id":"1"},{"Topic_id":"4","Subject":"languages","Details":"c and java","Parent_id":"1"}]}
```

"0":[]--From where does this comes from?

Comment: `$topicarray[] = array();` try removing `[]` after `$topicarray`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining an empty array in array. Try with -

```
$topicarray = array();
```